# Como agrupar array que tem o mesmo valor

Tags: php, array

Tenho a seguinte string que é convertido em uma array que representa: "Pergunta;ID da Matéria;Resposta":

```
//PEGANDO AS REPOSTAS
$respostasgabarito='1;1;A|2;1;B|3;1;C|4;1;A|5;1;A|6;2;D|7;2;C|8;2;B|9;2;A|10;2;A';

//SEPARANDO QUESTÕES PELO CARACTER "|"
$questoesgabarito=explode('|',$respostasgabarito);

//FOREACH PARA CADA PERGUNTA PARA SEPARAR PERGUNTA, MATERIA E RESPOSTA
foreach($questoesgabarito as $reposta){ 
    $dividequestoes = explode(';',$reposta);
    $pergunta = $dividequestoes[0];
    $materia = $dividequestoes[1];
    $resposta = $dividequestoes[2];
}
```

Como posso fazer para agrupar os `$materias` que forem iguais? Nesse caso, as repostas de 1 à 5 ficariam agrupadas e as de 6 à 10 outro grupo.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Comparar 2 array e trazer o resultado das diferenças (agrupados por um valor igual dentro da array)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/355689/comparar-2-array-e-trazer-o-resultado-das-diferen%c3%a7as-agrupados-por-um-valor-igu)

Comment: Parece ser a mesma pergunta... qual a diferença?

Comment: na verdade vou excluir a outra, eu simplifiquei o funcionamento

Answer (score 2):

Basta você definir um *array* que irá agrupar os valores, utilizando a matéria como chave desse *array*, armazenando os valores nas chaves conforme a matéria de cada item.

```
$gabarito = '1;1;A|2;1;B|3;1;C|4;1;A|5;1;A|6;2;D|7;2;C|8;2;B|9;2;A|10;2;A';

$materias = [];

foreach (explode('|', $gabarito) as $resposta) {
    list($pergunta, $materia, $alternativa) = str_getcsv($resposta, ';');

    if ( ! array_key_exists($materia, $materias)) {
        $materias[$materia] = [];
    }

    $materias[$materia][] = compact('pergunta', 'alternativa');
}

echo json_encode($materias, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

O resultado seria:

```
{
    "1": [
        {
            "pergunta": "1",
            "alternativa": "A"
        },
        {
            "pergunta": "2",
            "alternativa": "B"
        },
        {
            "pergunta": "3",
            "alternativa": "C"
        },
        {
            "pergunta": "4",
            "alternativa": "A"
        },
        {
            "pergunta": "5",
            "alternativa": "A"
        }
    ],
    "2": [
        {
            "pergunta": "6",
            "alternativa": "D"
        },
        {
            "pergunta": "7",
            "alternativa": "C"
        },
        {
            "pergunta": "8",
            "alternativa": "B"
        },
        {
            "pergunta": "9",
            "alternativa": "A"
        },
        {
            "pergunta": "10",
            "alternativa": "A"
        }
    ]
}
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/ZanyRoastedAdmins) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/GNkIi4) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/acwoss/aaea2d99c784ef3c280c4fffe1ad847b)</sup>

Comment: show, mas tem como ao invez de retornar json_encode($materias, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); ele traga em 2 arrays?

Comment: Tem, isso você tem capacidade de fazer sozinho, basta entender o que o código faz. Só converti para JSON para exibir um resultado mais limpo.

Answer (score 1):

Bastaria acrescentar algo do tipo dentro do `for`:

```
$resultado[$materia][] = ['pergunta' => $pergunta, 'resposta' => $resposta];
```

No final ficaria como:

```
//VALOR PADRÃO DO RESULTADO AGRUPADO
$resultado = [];

//PEGANDO AS REPOSTAS
$respostasgabarito='1;1;A|2;1;B|3;1;C|4;1;A|5;1;A|6;2;D|7;2;C|8;2;B|9;2;A|10;2;A'; 

//SEPARANDO QUESTÕES PELO CARACTER "|"
$questoesgabarito=explode('|',$respostasgabarito);

//FOREACH PARA CADA PERGUNTA PARA SEPARAR PERGUNTA, MATERIA E RESPOSTA
foreach($questoesgabarito as $reposta){ 
    list($pergunta, $materia, $resposta) = explode(';', $reposta);

    $resultado[$materia][] = ['pergunta' => $pergunta, 'resposta' => $resposta];        
}
```